# shared_ptr failed to be pushed to vector

Tags: c++, boost, containers, shared-ptr

I have vector of boost shared_ptr, however, when I push to the end of locally made new shared_ptr, it fails. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with following code?

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr< A > > vecA;

BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string& s, vecStrings)
{
   boost::shared_ptr<A> pNewA = boost::make_shared<A>(s);
   pNewA->MyString(); //OK
   vecA.push_back(pNewA); //throw error Assertion `px != 0' failed
}
```

UPDATE:
It seems like not the problem of pushing, but I used a reference to shared_ptr.

```
 for(int i=0, n=vecA.size(); i <n; i++)
{

    //use pA
     boost::shared_ptr& pA = vecA[i];
     vecA.push_back(pA);
    //will core dump at the end of loop because pA changed due to vector enlarge
}
```

Comment: What is `A`? What is `pNewA->MyString()` ?

Comment: I suspect [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Try to reproduce your problem in a smaller sample. Gradually eliminate sources of the error until it disappears.

Comment: A is just a structure with a string member and two integer member.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure why you use the boost librarys there(not too familiar with them) but shared pointers are also in the standard lib memory

```
#include <memory>
```

Most likely it is a problem with the ownership of the shared pointer object. If written with standard libs the correct code would look something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

//...

std::vector<std::shared_pointer<A> > vecA;

//version 1
std::shared_ptr<A> pNewA = std::make_shared<A>(s);
pNewA->MyString();
vecA.push_back(std::move(pNewA)); //std::move moves ownership to vector

//or alternativeley
vecA.push_back(std::shared_pointer<A>(new class A(s)));
```

or something along those lines..

HTH

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` has a copy constructor, so `std::move()` should not be necessary when pushing a `std::shared_ptr` into a container. On the other hand, if you were using `std::unique_ptr` instead then you would need the `std::move()` since `std::unique_ptr` does not have a copy constructor but does have a move constructor. Either way, if you really want to push a new object, consider using `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`.

Comment: didnt look into c++14 yet, so emplace_back() is new for me. Thanks!

Comment: `emplace_back()` was added in C++11, same as `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared()`.

Comment: `emplace_back` has no benefit if you're using a move or copy ctor

Comment: I had to use boost in the project because I have to link to another library without c++11 support. Boost version should not have much difference than std version, at least I think?